# Different behavior in OfficeJs on search/replace between desktop and web application

Tags: reactjs, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I have an MS Word Add-in, written in React.

The main purpose of this add-in is to assist in turning a Word document into a template which will be filled by an outside service. One of the things a user is able to do is add tags to their document, in the style of `<< VariableName >>`, press a button in the add-in, and have these tags replaced by Content Controls which are recognized by the add-in as being intended for replacement.

In the desktop application, this works correctly. If a user enters the following in the document:

```
<< Var1 >> << Var2 >>
```

And presses the match/replace button, it's replaced by:

```
[Var1] [Var2]
```

where [Var1] and [Var2] are encased in Content Controls.

However, in the web application, the exact same line is replaced by:

```
[Var1] << V[Var2]
```

instead, with Content Controls correctly around the square brackets but the wrong text having been replaced for the second tag.

---

As far as I can tell, in the web application, what's happening is that when replacing multiple items on a single line, when next replacing any content after the first item, Word doesn't yet realize that the content has been updated with content of different length, so when it goes to replace things it replaces the wrong piece of text. It's very interesting that this doesn't seem to occur in the desktop application.

Here is the code which does the find and replace:

```
Word.run((context) => {
  const results = context.document.body.search('[<][<] * [>][>]', { matchWildcards: true });
  context.load(results);

  return context.sync().then(() => {
    results.items.forEach((item) => {
      const text = item.text.replace(/^(<< )/, '').replace(/( >>)$/, '');
      const matchingVariable = byDisplay[text];
      if (matchingVariable) {
        item.insertText(`[${text}]`, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
        const contentControl = item.insertContentControl();
        contentControl.removeWhenEdited = true;
      }
    });
  }).then(context.sync)
```

If you inspect the array of ranges that is results.items, they each seem to reflect the correct text values on both web and desktop Word.

Any thoughts or suggestions are very much welcome. Thanks!

Comment: A difference in API behavior between platforms is probably a bug. Please give the community a couple of days to answer. If you don't get an answer, open a bug on the [Office.js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose).

Comment: I'd suggest filing a bug report on the `OfficeJS` repo on GitHub.

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2800) - Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thanks for reaching us. We replied to you on Github. Just FYI.